Cast as type not working when stored value created elsewhere
I'm on a project based in Xcode frameworks and CocoaPods at the start of converting to SPM modules. There are a lot of individual frameworks to convert and we are trying to do it piecemeal.
The problem I have encountered is that we have an in-house DI framework that's storing dependencies to be injected. Here's a vastly simplified version:
protocol Dependency {
    associatedtype BoxType
    var value: BoxType { get }
}

struct Box<T>: Dependency {
   let value: T
}

private var dependencies: [String: any Dependency]

func resolve<T>(key: String) -> T {
    (dependencies[key] as! Box<T>).value
}

Now the problem we are encountering is that when we attempt to resolve some dependencies, dependencies[key] as! Box<T> fails even though we know there is a box for that key and it was created with the correct type.
We've even confirmed this with a much verbose version of resolve(…) where we compare the generic type of Box with T.self and they match. They're the same time from the same module.
Were it's going wrong is when we're dealing with registrations and resolving that go through the Xcode framework/SPM module boundaries. In those cases we're finding that the type stored in the box might be MySPMModule.MyType.Protocol where as the generic type being passed to the function is @Thick MySPMModule.MyType.Protocol. In these cases, the cast fails.
Our current theory is that this is something to do with crossing the Xcode framework/SPM module boundaries. @Thick … in the debugger having a memory address where as the normal types don't so I'm guessing that in crossing the boundary the type is being put on the heap and this is somehow coming through. So when we attempt to do dependencies[key] as! Box<T> fails because the Box in the store is a Box<T> where as we're actually trying to cast to Box<@Thick T> and T is not equal to @Thick T.
Any thoughts?

Look's like you doesn't need box at all and can store your dependencies as just: [String: Any]

As I said this is simplified. The actual code has a variety of boxes. This is just the simplest.
